# Need HTML Form to Submit Multiple Rows into SQL Database

Tags: php, sql

So I just got done with figuring out some javascript issues with my form in this topic: [How Can I Insert Multiple Rows Into a DB from my HTML Form with Multiple Rows Dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255737/how-can-i-insert-multiple-rows-into-a-db-from-my-html-form-with-multiple-rows-dy/15256207?noredirect=1#comment21800291_15256207)

But since I had such a multi-part question I have been asked to create a new topic. Below is my new code that I am using where I am stuck and wanting to be able to submit my form, which has the capability if adding multiple rows, to my database and add those HTML rows to rows in the SQL database, respectively.

PREVIEW: http://cl.ly/image/0K0Z202O1Q3e/Screen%20Shot%202013-03-14%20at%203.00.19%20PM.png

**HTML**

```
<html>
<header>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/jquery/js/jquery-1.9.1.js">      
</script>
<script src="http://www.mapquestapi.com/sdk/js/v7.0.s/mqa.toolkit.js?   
key=Gmjtd%7Cluua2q6bn9%2C8g%3Do5-lzbsh"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<title>Central Office Company Survey</title>
</header>
<body onload="get_company_name();">
<h1>Central Office Company Survey</h1>
<div id='map' style='width:0px; height:0px; position:absolute'></div>

<input type="hidden" id="co_city" name="co_city">
<input type="hidden" id="co_state" name="co_state">
<input type="hidden" id="co_zipcode" name="co_zipcode">

<table>
<th>Company</th>
<th>CO Name</th>
<th>Get Current Location</th>
<th>Lat</th>
<th>Long</th>
<th>Address</th>
<tr>
    <td><select id="company_name" name="company_name" /></select></td>
    <td><input name="co_name" type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Get GPS" onclick="gpslookup();" /></td>
    <td><input id="co_lat" name="co_lat" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input id="co_long" name="co_long" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input id="co_address" name="co_address" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table id="tabledata">
<thead>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>Border Location Name</th>
    <th>Cable Location</th>
    <th>Direction of Vault Wall</th>
    <th>Cable Type</th>
    <th>Cable Size (pairs)</th>
    <th>Cable Gauge</th>
    <th>Vertical(s) appeared on Verticals</th>
    <th>Approximate Number of Jumpers</th>
    <th>Are Protectors Still In?</th>
    <th>Metered Distance</th>
    <th class="comments">Central Office Comments</th>
</thead>
<tbody id="input"></tbody>
<tbody id="template">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input name="border_location" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input name="cable_location" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input name="vault_direction" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input name="cable_type" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input name="cable_size" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input name="cable_gauge" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input name="vertical" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input name="jumpers" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input name="protectors" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input name="metered_dist" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input name="comments" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button id="ActionAddRow">Add Row</button>
<button onclick="deleteRow(); return false;">Delete Row</button>
<button id="ActionSubmit">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**scripts.js**

```
//Button Functions
$(function () {
var addInputRow = function () {
    $('#input').append($('#template').html());
};

addInputRow();
$('#ActionAddRow').on('click', addInputRow);
$('#ActionSubmit').on('click', function () {
    var data = $('#input tr').map(function () {
        var values = {};
        $('input', $(this)).each(function () {
            values[this.name] = this.value;
        });
        return values;
    }).get();
    $.post('./php/upload_survey.php', {
        json: JSON.stringify(data),
        delay: 1
    }).done(function (response) {
        alert("Thank you. Your form has been submitted.");
        console.log(response);
    });
});
});

//Delete Selected Rows
function deleteRow() {
 try {
    var table = document.getElementById("tabledata");
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            if(rowCount <= 3) {
                alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                break;
            }
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
catch(e) {
    alert(e);
}
};
```

**upload_survey.php**

```
//Assign passed parameters
    $values = json_decode($_POST['json']);

    $stringLogInfo =  "INFO: Location: $co_address CO Name = $co_name !!!\n\n";
    log_audit($logAuditFile, $logModule, $stringLogInfo);

//Parse and store the ini file, this will return an associative array
ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//Insert Survey Form Information into the database
$sql="INSERT INTO table_name (company_name,...,...) 
VALUES ($values)";

mysql_query($sql) or die ("Unable to Make Query:" . mysql_error());
```

**So far every time I try to get this working the JS fires successfully, but I get an error in Chrome's Developer Toolbox: Unable to Make Query:Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

This refers to this function in js file: console.log(response);

Comment: gah. kill this code now, with fire, or at least nuke it from orbit. [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com) galore... Your error message is an SQL error, due to how (horribly badly) you're building your query.

Comment: i don't like it either, but I don't know any better, sadly.

Comment: stop being lazy and build the query the long way. you're just begging to get your server destroyed.

Comment: haha well I know it's a SQL error, but I want to know how to PROPERLY create a prepared SQL statement that will work the way I am wanting it to as explained above. So yes, I know it's SQL error and yes I don't claim I know much of anything with SQL, but I am learning. So far none of this works anyway, so if you're just referring to the ($values) in the VALUE area of the SQL statement, I am not wanting to do it that way that's just there as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no such thing as batch inserts in PHP. There is no equivalent for JAVA's addBatch & executeBatch.

So the right way to do it is simply iteratation over array and insert single row with prepared statement.

Comment: so essentially a for each structure with a SQL statement inside it??